# How to keep multiple method channels in same flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that I can access multiple `MethodChannel` through dart code but how should I implement multiple `MethodChannel` on the platform code without using multiple plugins.

I've tried searching but every documentation & article but they show only a single Method channel per plugin as

```
override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "org.my.application/channel")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
  }
```

In the above Flutter plugin's `onAttachedToEngine`, I've created a single channel with the name "org.my.application/channel", how can I make more in that same plugin?

My only alternative now is to use divide my implementation of different method channels in multiple plugins.

Is there a way possible to keep them in a single plugin?

Comment: what is the problem with multiple `MethodChannel`s? you simply use different `String name` and you can have any number of channels you want

Comment: I don't know how to create multiple MethodChannel in a single package.

Comment: use different `String name` when calling `MethodChannel` constructor

Comment: I can access multiple channels through dart side but how to implement multiple method channels on Platform side without using multiple packages

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: I've updated my question, please check

Comment: so use `channel1 = MethodChannel(...); channel1.setMethodCallHandler(handler1); channel2 = MethodChannel(...); channel2.setMethodCallHandler(handler2);` - whats the problem with multiple channels and multiple handlers?

Comment: Did you find a way ? or creating  multiple channels and multiple handlers works fine ?

Comment: Yes, @pskink's comment solves the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Basically, just create a new MethodChannel and set its `MethodCallHandler`.

```
override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    final MethodChannel methodChannel = new MethodChannel(messenger, yourPackageName, codec);
    methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    
    // Just create a MethodChannel with a different channel name.
    final MethodChannel specialMethodChannel = new MethodChannel(messenger, yourPackageName + ".specialMethodChannel", codec);
    specialMethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
  }
```

You could alternatively create a new class which implements the `MethodCallHandler` interface, instead of sharing the same method call handler (`this`) when you call `setMethodCallHandler(this)`.

---

I found this when looking how to create multiple MethodChannels corresponding to the same channel name across different threads or parts of the app. This is because each MethodChannel can only be used in one thread.