# Can I have more than one lib classes in Flutter plugin

Tags: android, ios, flutter, libraries, flutter-plugin

First of all, I am new to Flutter plugin. And I think there is not much documentation on it. Here is my question:

I am building a Flutter plugin that include custom native Android and iOS libraries. The library has a few classes that are exposed to app developers. My question is: Can I create the same number of classes in the Flutter plugin's lib and iOS and Android's Classes folders? These classes correspond to the original libraries' exposed classes. I don't want to use one handleMethodCall (iOS) or one onMethodCall (Android) to handle all the methods from these classes in the original libraries.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can create one dart class for each native class and every class uses its own methodchannel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548667/how-to-keep-multiple-method-channels-in-same-flutter-application

Comment: @Colin. Thanks! In that case, on the app developers' side, they can just do: import 'package:pakagename/*.dart' to get all the classes?

Comment: You're welcome :) You can export your files and then the app developer using your plugin can just do import 'package:your_plugin': 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579092/how-to-avoid-writing-an-import-for-every-single-file-in-dart-flutter